# Practical advice for determining the distance between two prominent buildings

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, plane-geometry

From the window of my apartment, I can see two remarkable buildings. I can also spot those two buildings from the place where I work. But I can not spot my apartment from work and I can not spot my working place from my apartment.
Let me refer to the big buildings as tower 1 ($T_1$) and tower 2 ($T_2$), and to my home and working place as $H$ and $W$, respectively.
I have drawn an overview of the situation:

[image: Overview of the situation]

I tried to figure out some of the distances between any two of the four places (There are six lines in total between the four buildings.), or at least the ratio between two of these distances. Just to give you an idea of the situation, my guess is that all six pairwise distances are between 1.5 and 4.5 kilometres.

At first sight, this will not work. I only know two angles, namely $\alpha := \angle T_2 H T_1$ and $\beta :=\angle T_2 W T_1$. I think (am I right?) I have no chance to find out anything about the ratio of the distances from these two angles.

So I became more creative and thought about ways to gain more information. The ground plot of $T_2$ is rectangular, I would even guess it is a square. $T_2$ appears from different perspectives depending on my point of view. By comparing the length of wall segments I see of both visible sides of the tower (and doing this from my apartment as well as from my working place), I can determine the angle $\chi := \angle H T_2 W$. (For a thorough explanation, see footnote [3] below.)

Unfortunately, the building $T_1$ is of circular ground view, so I think I can not apply a similar trick there.

Another idea: I have access to the roof of my working place. (From there, I see the two buildings.) So this is where information about actual (non-relative) distances could enter the picture. However, I can only move maybe 7 metres in one direction before falling off the roof. I suppose this will practically not be enough to get new information, since the inaccuracy when measuring is too high. Right?

I think that knowing $\alpha, \beta, \chi$ is still not enough to gain new information, is it?
So my question is: How could I collect more information about the situation, and how would it help me to determine the distance between any two of the four buildings? Creative ideas welcomed.

[3] How to determine $\chi$, using the shape of tower 2:
This picture

[image: How to determine chi, using the shape of tower 2]

could be helpful for understanding the idea. (Maybe looking at the picture is more helpful than reading the typed explanation.)
When I look in the direction of tower 2 from my apartment, then I see two of its side walls.  When I look from my working place, I also see two side walls. In both situations, the prominent side (i.e. the side which "I can see better" or "more") is the same.

Let's focus on the perspective from my apartment, first. Using a somewhat unlucky notation, I denoted as $\alpha$ the angle between the prominent side of tower 2 and the direct connecting line $\overline{T_2 H}$. You can see a sketch in the lower right corner of my uploaded image. From my apartment, the prominent side of tower 2 appears to be $y$ wide; the other side appears to be $x$ wide. Some trigonometry gives $x : y = \cos \alpha : \sin \alpha$. I can measure $x$ and $y$ and then solve this equation for $\alpha \in [0°, 90°]$.

The angle between the non-prominent side of tower 2 and $\overline{T_2 H}$ is just $90° - \alpha$. Proceding similarly, I can determine the angle between the non-prominent side of tower 2 and $\overline{T_2 W}$. Their sum is $\chi$.

Comment: Do you own a compass? That can confirm the information from your $HT_2W$ trick by comparing relative angles between locations. Can you use the visual size of the buildings to compute relative distances? For example, if building 1 is the same as 2 in one view, but twice as big in the other, you know that the ratio in the distances changed by a factor of 2. That should be enough to somehow get all the relative distances.

Comment: @Eric37 The compass is a good idea, thanks! It will also work for $\angle H T_1 W$. I have only a vague idea what you mean with the second sentence, could you elaborate on that?

Comment: +1 good definition of problem and description of effort. Note that if you can see the round tower from both viewpoints, then by comparing its apparent diameter from the two viewpoints you can calculate the ratio of its distances to the two viewpoints, namely, $T_1 H : T_1 W$

Comment: @Saeed Oh, that's a good idea. Thank you!

Comment: If you can estimate the height of one of the towers by counting the number of stories, and measure the angle from the bottom to the top of the tower from your home, you can use that information as a basis for estimating the distance from your home to the tower.

Comment: @awkward "stories" means "stones"? I can not see the bottom of any of the towers from home or working place; however, your idea will also work if I measure the height on from a specific height $h_0$ of the tower, right? Only I don't quite understand how I can infer the distance to the tower from the height of the tower and the angle $\angle T_{\text{bottom}} H T_{\text{top}}$. What's your idea for this? Or do you intend to assume that both lines are "almost parallel"?

Comment: If the angle from the bottom to the top of a tower is small, then $x = h / \theta$ should be a good approximation, where $h$=height of tower, $x$ = distance to tower, and $\theta$= angle from bottom to top, in radians.

Comment: @awkward OK, I see. So this will rely much on me being able to determine or estimate the height of the tower, which I think I am not. Your suggestion was merely to guess, or did I miss something there?

Comment: Yes, my suggestion relies on your having an estimate of the height.  If you don't have such an estimate, please ignore the suggestion.

Comment: @Saeed After thinking about it for a while, I wondered whether there is a standard method to determine an "apparent diameter". My naive idea is to hold a ruler in my hand with my arm stretched out, to have a reproducible distance between my eyes and the ruler; however this seems pretty imprecise. What did you have in mind?

Comment: That's a good question. In the text you mentioned that you compared lengths of wall segments of visible sides of the square tower. From this I understood that you have a technique for measuring those visible side lengths. You can use the same technique for measuring diameter of the round tower. 
What you suggest in the above comment makes sense. Just make sure the ruler is horizontal when reading.

Comment: @Saeed Now I see how you thought that I "had a technique". But when comparing lengths of wall segments of the square tower (tower 2), I can "measure" the apparent lengths both at the same time. However when I need the apparent diameter of tower 1 from different points of view, then this is not possible. I can perform this idea to hold a ruler at an arm-length distance to my eyes – but I am not sure about the implied inaccuracies.

Comment: I can think of 2 sources of inaccuracy: (1) from different orientations of the ruler in your hand, and (2) from differences in your arm length. You can resolve the first issue by trying several readings (each with a slightly different orientation of the ruler) and taking note of the smallest value in each site. The second issue depends on your posture at each moment; I can't think of a solution for it.